# Function that toggles text repeatedly on single click

Tags: javascript, function, text, toggle

So I have a function that processes some user input and then displays the results. What I would like to do is have the displayed results toggle between two sets of text. The function runs when I click a button on the page. Currently I have it set to display a different message depending on what time the button is clicked.

```
myFunction1()
{
    // does a whole bunch of other stuff...
    myFunction2(value1, value2, today.getSeconds());
}
myFunction2(x, y, z)
{
    if (z % 10 >= 5)
        document.getElementById("element1").innerHTML= x + " My Text " + y ;
    else
        document.getElementById("element1").innerHTMLx + " Alt Text " + y ;
}
```

So instead of this I would want the myFunction2 to repeat every 5 seconds, toggling the text each time. I tried using setTimeout but I didn't seem to have much luck. Maybe I wasn't using it correctly. I want to only have to click the button once and have the text continue switching until I reset the form. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval to toggle every 5 seconds:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    myTimer();
}, 5000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
```

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/skhan/nz6Jf/

Comment: Thanks! Setting a variable to the setInterval worked out for me. It let me modify it later on easier too.

Comment: Glad it helped for you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` to trigger a function periodically, something like this:

```
setInterval( 
    function(){ myFunction2(value1, value2, today.getSeconds()); },
    5000
)
```

You can trigger it when you click your button the first time.